# how to make bootable windows iso on kali linux? error

Tags: windows, windows-10

`sudo dd if=/home/user/Downloads/windows10.iso of=/dev/sdb
sync`

I followed this method but when I plug in the pendrive to install windows 10 
I  get an error " boot device not found insert cd/usb and click or enter...."
What do I do?

Comment: I am getting error thats why ive asked again!!

Comment: `dd` will make a bootable pendrive only if the iso is a hybrid iso.  Otherwise, you need to add the boot provisions using a third party utility.  Also, the boot provisions need to match the computer provisions (i.e., UEFI).  Can you update your question in relation to those considerations?

Answer (score 0):

Use command `lsblk` to display the disks, and use the name (sdX) corresponding to your USB in place of "sdb" in your command.

Comment: Your answer is a bit cryptic as to what you're describing and how to use it to solve the problem.  Can you expand on this, and add an explicit example?  Thanks.